# Does the out parameter in Dictionary.TryGetValue point by reference to the value

Tags: c#, dictionary, reference

Consider if I have a `Dictionary<Key,List<item>>` `TestDictionary`

If I do:

```
List<item> someCollection;
TestDictionary.TryGetValue(someKey,out someCollection); //assuming that someCollection will not return null;
someCollection.add(someItem);
```

Will the object `someItem` be added to the collection in the `Dictionary` value `TestDictionary[someKey]` ?

Comment: yes, you could have tried for yourself.

Comment: Actually you can prove it by printing the dictionary items.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you will have a reference of the object if it is a Ref type, and of course a copy if it is a Value type

Comment: Unless you're using a boxed Value type (put an integer into an Object list). Then you'll have a boxed Reference to a Value type.

Comment: @CodingBarfield No that is not my case, but good to know ;)

Comment: It is not that obvious. Having experience with other languages, one could expect to always get a reference. With this logic, TryGetValue is much less useful for value types.

Comment: Looks like .NET 7 will support ref returns for value types https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27062

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet posted [great article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) on this regard. But, anyway, here code snippet that can help you:

```
class Item
{}

void Main()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
    dictionary[1] = new Item();

    Item i1;
    Item i2;

    dictionary.TryGetValue(1, out i1);
    dictionary.TryGetValue(1, out i2);

    Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(i1, i2));
}
```